# Check if a variable contains only what I want, and nothing else

Tags: bash, grep

I'm writing a script to build a software from sources, and there's a `--platforms` option. I would like to allow the user to select multiple items, but I don't know how to prevent them from making a mistake.

Example:

```
read -p "For what platforms do you wish to build [mac/win/linux32/linux64/all] ? "

if [[ -n "`echo $REPLY | grep 'win\|mac\|linux32\|linux64\|all`" ]] ; then
    echo "ok"
else 
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

If the user answers `linux32`, it should be OK (and it is)

If the user answers `linux32,mac`, it should be OK (and it is)

If the user answers `lulz`, it should NOT be OK (and it is not)

If the user answers `linux32,lulz`, it should NOT be OK (and it is, that's my issue)

I was wondering if you knew a way to allow the user to input whatever they want separated by commas, but only if it's one of the options the script is offering, so in this case `linux32 linux64 mac win all`.

Maybe with `case` there is a way to allow multiple inputs, or maybe add an `elif $REPLY contains anything else than what we want`. Another idea, could `awk` be used? I can't figure out myself how to do that.

Comment: Mac is not a platform, OS X is. (Not Mac OS X!)

Comment: Mac is the option that `--platforms=` reads, and not OSX. That is how the build works, and I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified/improved version of [arnefm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70193/arnefm)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134014/3730):

```
read -p 'Enter a comma-separated list of platforms to build for [win/mac/linux32/linux64/all]: ' input
IFS=',' read -a options <<< "$input"

shopt -s extglob

for option in "${options[@]}"; do
    case "$option" in
        win|mac|linux@(32|64)|all)
            buildcommand="${buildcommand:+$buildcommand,}$option"
            buildvar=1;;
        *)
            printf 'Invalid option "%s" ignored.\n' "$option" >&2;;
    esac
done

IFS=',' read -a options <<< "$buildcommand"

for option in "${options[@]}"; do
    if [[ $option == 'all' ]]; then
        buildcommand='all'
        break
    fi
done

if (( !buildvar )); then
    echo 'Incorrect input. Default build selected.' >&2
    buildcommand='default'
fi
```

Comment: `osx` is not a valid choice for `--platforms=` option.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: As far as I'm concern, you're right, it should be "osx" but not according to the sources I'm building : https://github.com/popcorn-official/popcorn-app/blob/dev-0.3/Gruntfile.js

Comment: Works well, but I'm also trying to isolate `all`, to output only "all" if the input was "mac,win,all" or "all,linux32"

Comment: @MrVaykadji - my answer does the `all` isolation already. Actually, what it does is replace any input containing `all` with all other possibilities.

Comment: How about this (http://pastebin.com/br2QEue5) instead, allowing it to display every "Invalid option" messages even if the input is "lulz,mac,all,nope,win" ?

Comment: I implemented that in my answer now, but in a better way.

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/. It's a really good resource for shell/bash scripting. Specifically [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) and [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) is relevant.

Comment: @nyuszika7h - your code has a lot of portability problems. This is especially relevant considering that this seems to be a build script. I have updated my answer also to handle error reporting - all in a single pipeline. Can you elaborate on what is better and what isn't?

Comment: @mikeserv What portability issues are you referring to? I can't see any portability issues other than bashisms, which are a non-issue since the question is tagged [tag:bash].

Comment: @nyuszika7h - the `bash` tag point is a good one, withdrawn. It is a good script - but would you please elaborate on the other thing? specifically what is better than the other?

Comment: If you mean compared to arnefm's answer, I'm not sure other than it being simpler and cleaner code. If you're referring to your answer, this is the wrong comments section to discuss that.

Comment: @nyuszika7h - no, I don't mean that. I agree with that point. I mean you say you implemented the *all* thing in a *better way* - what did you do differently?

Comment: I meant better than MrVaykadji's proposal, which might work in this particular case, but isn't really a clean solution. Passing a variable to `echo`, especially as first argument, and it's not even quoted (see my previous links). That `grep` might match more than expected, though not in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

`read` can break the input into words and store the result in an array. Set the `IFS` variable to the word separator character (it needs to be a single character, not a string — if the value of `IFS` contains multiple characters, then each character is a word separator).

```
IFS=, read -a platforms
```

Then check each element of the array against the set of supported platforms.

```
for p in "${platforms[@]}"; do
  case "$p" in
    win|mac|linux32|linux64) :;;
    all) platforms=(win mac linux32 linux64);;
    *) printf 1>&2 "Unsupported platform: %s\n" "$p"; return 2;;
  esac
done
```

You can also compare the set of platforms in one go. This is more convenient if you don't want to hardcode the set of supported platforms in the checking code¹.

```
supported_platforms=(win mac linux32 linux64)
IFS=, read -a platforms
bad_platform_names=($(comm -23 <(printf '%s\n' all "${platforms[@]}" | sort -u) \
                               <(printf '%s\n' "${supported_platforms[@]}" | sort -u)))
if [[ ${#bad_platform_names[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
  printf "Unsupported platform: %s\n" "${bad_platform_names[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
if printf '%s\n' "${platforms[@]}" | grep -qx all; then
  platforms=("${supported_platforms[@]}")
fi
```

A different approach would be to prompt for platforms one at a time using the `select` builtin.

¹  <sub>Of course you can do this in pure bash if you prefer.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I always have the "unsupported platform:" message and it also only records the first input.

Comment: @MrVaykadji Typo fixed

Comment: It still only records the first input, and the second is always stated as unsupported, even if it should be ok. I don't understand

Comment: @MrVaykadji I've tested both snippets this time. The first worked, the second had several more typos.

Comment: I can't use the first one, I'm sorry, it doesn't seem to work, or I'm doing things wrong. Check : http://pastebin.com/in35yd8T

Comment: @MrVaykadji The bug is in your last line: `$platforms` is the first element of the array (this is a quirk of ksh and bash syntax). You need `"${platforms[@]}"` to get the list of elements in the array.

Comment: Okay thanks ! That's what I wasn't understanding. Now, I've managed with the answer from arnfm to output exactly what I want, that is with the input "linux32,lol,mac" print "linux32,mac". But this is working too

Answer (score 5):

Try this!

```
buildvar=0
read -p "For what platforms do you wish to build [mac/win/linux32/linux64/all] ? " input
IFS=',' read -a options <<< "$input"

for option in "${options[@]}"
 do
  case "$option" in
    linux32)
        buildcommand="linux32" && buildvar=1
        ;;
    linux64)
        [ $buildvar == 1 ] && buildcommand="$buildcommand",linux64 || buildcommand="linux64" && buildvar=1
        ;;  
    mac)
        [ $buildvar == 1 ] && buildcommand="$buildcommand",mac || buildcommand="mac" && buildvar=1
        ;;  
    win)
        [ $buildvar == 1 ] && buildcommand="$buildcommand",win || buildcommand="win" && buildvar=1
        ;;
    all)
        buildcommand="all" && buildvar=1
        ;;
    *) 
        echo "'$option' was ignored." 
        ;;  
        esac
    done

[ $buildvar == "0" ] && echo "Incorrect input. Default build selected." && buildcommand="default"

echo "=> $buildcommand"
```

This will prompt for a comma separated list of options. It will then split this list into an array and iterate through the elements checking each element separately, then combine all "good" elements into a single variable.

Comment: Thanks, I had to rewrite some of it, but it's working like a charm :)

Comment: You have set `IFS` generally for the script which can cause unexpected consequences later. You can set it only for the environment of the `read` command by prefixing the `IFS=,` there as in Gilles answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can read a single line of input with `sed` and translate the delimiter to newlines like:

```
% sed 'y/,/\n/;q' /dev/tty
> this,is,a,single,line
##OUTPUT
this
is
a
single
line
```

Because `sed` writes the result to stdout as a text file, following that up with an e`x`plicit `grep` is easy and occurs in a single stream. And, in fact, you can use `sed` like a smart `tee` if you make use of its `w`rite to file function; and, if you `w`rite to file descriptor devices, you can split its output based on rules you define.

A function that prompts for input and outputs only a newline delimited list of acceptable arguments to stdout and erroneous output to stderr might look like:

```
_accept_prompt() (
   . /dev/fd/0
   IFS=${delim-,}
   _prompt "$@" >&2
   { _read_split "$@" |
        err=all _grep_ok "$@" |
        sed '1{$d}' >&2
   } 3>&1 | _grep_ok "$@"
) <<\HELPERS

_prompt() {
    cat ; printf ' : '
} <<-PROMPT
    Choose from : $(printf "'%s' " "$@")
    Enter a '$IFS'-delimited selection below...
PROMPT

_read_split() {
    y="y/${IFS}/\n/"
    sed -ne "H;x;s/^/Invalid input IGNORED:/;${y};p;x" \
        -ne "/all/s/.*/$*/;${y};w /dev/fd/3" -ne q
} </dev/tty

_grep_ok() {
    grep -${err+v}xF "$(printf '%s\n' "$@" $err)"
}
HELPERS
```

I split this into *hopefully* more descriptively named helper functions in lieu of the comments and attached them to the main function. So the flow all happens in the first few lines. I hoped to make this clearer.

`_read_split` outputs two streams - `>&1` and `>&3`. `_grep_ok` picks up the first with `$err` defined and writes to `>&2` all lines contained in its input that are not among `_accept_prompt`'s positional parameters.

`_grep_ok` *also concurrently* picks up the second stream - `>&3` and writes to its `>&1 stdout` all lines in its input that *are* among `_accept_prompt`'s positional parameters.

Running it:

```
% _accept_prompt this is the list of acceptable parameters
###PROMPT
    Choose from : 'this' 'is' 'the' 'list' 'of' 'acceptable' 'parameters'
    Enter a ','-delimited selection below...
###INPUT
 : all,invalid
###STDOUT
this
is
the
list
of
acceptable
parameters
###STDERR
Invalid input IGNORED:
invalid
```

You can alter the default `,`comma delimiter on invocation like:

```
delim=? _accept_prompt $args
```

Comment: I find that code difficult to read.

Comment: It might be just me, but I find it too complicated.

Comment: I also am kind of lost reading that^^ But it's interresting

Comment: @MrVaykadji - is it any clearer now? I tried...

Comment: Yes, very much !

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming you already have some way of getting the variables in from input, since you mentioned a --platforms option.  You can use regular expressions to match on the valid conditions.

```
regex='^(mac|win|linux(32|64)|all)(,(mac|win|linux(32|64)|all))*$'
if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then 
  echo "ok"
else 
  echo "not ok"
fi
```

That should satisfy all the requirements:

```
$ ./stack.sh linux32
ok
$ ./stack.sh linux32,mac
ok
$ ./stack.sh lulz
not ok
$ ./stack.sh linux32,lulz
not ok
```

Granted, this doesn't stop people from using "all,all,all,all", but that at least can be trimmed down when actually running stuff later.

Benefits of this method include being able to loop until the user gets it right, if you're using the read command you have in the first post.  Drawbacks include being a bit confusing to just glance at.

```
regex='^(mac|win|linux(32|64)|all)(,(mac|win|linux(32|64)|all))*$'
while ! [[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]]; do
  read -p "For what platforms do you wish to build [mac/win/linux32/linux64/all] ? "
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternate method as suggested by Gilles, get users to input as little as possible by prompting them for the options.

```
available_platforms="mac win linux32 linux64"

positive() {
  printf "%s (Answer y for yes or anything else for no) " "$1"
  read answer
  if [ "$answer" != "y" ] && [ "$answer" != "Y" ]; then
    return 1
  fi
}

if positive "Do you want to build for all platforms [$available_platforms]?"; then
  build_platforms="$available_platforms"
else
  for platform in $available_platforms; do
    if positive "Do you want to build for [$platform]?"; then
      build_platforms="${build_platforms}${platform} "
    fi
  done
fi

printf "build_platforms: %s\n" "$build_platforms"
```